# Http302 Response when using Ajax to post to Django view

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to build a web app that takes input using ajax. The input is sent server-side to Django and I'm having a hard time with getting the url to redirect properly. I understand that the issue at the moment has something to do with the django translation application.

Here's the relevant sections.

**Ajax**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#applicant_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault() //this will stop the file from submitting the form manually.
    $.ajax({
        url :'/save_applicant/', // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { the_post : "Yay" }, // data sent with the post request
        dataType: "json",
        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML/DJANGO TEMPLATES**

```
<form method = "POST" action = "" class="form bgform" id="applicant_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ applicant_form|crispy }}
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="Save" />
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def save_applicant(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    id = None
    if 'applicant' in request.session:
        id = request.session['applicant']

    applicant_form = ApplicantForm(request.POST)
    if applicant_form.is_valid():
        session_applicant  = applicant_form.save(commit=False)
        if id:
            session_applicant.id = id
        else:
            session_applicant.save()
            request.session['applicant'] = session_applicant.id 
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':'applicant_saved'}), content_type='application/json')

    else:
        return HttpResponse(applicant_form.errors.as_json(),content_type='application/json')

else:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':'not_post'}),content_type='application/json')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', 'plan_b_profile.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^save_applicant/','plan_b_profile.views.save_applicant',name='save_applicant'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**Command Line**

```
[21/Aug/2015 20:53:43]"POST /save_applicant HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[21/Aug/2015 20:53:43]"GET /en/save_applicant/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22 <---- HOW TO FIX THIS
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: Is that the whole view?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: hey i added the full view, sorry I wasn't sure if it was relevant. I'm just trying to use ajax to POST to /save_applicant/. I have translation on though and instead of just posting to the url as it normally does, it changes to a GET call and adds /en/save_applicant/ . Not sure how to fix this so this redirect does not happen.

Comment: It's doing a `GET` because you are submitting a form and not using `$.preventDefault()`. I'm assuming the page reloads once hit submit?

Comment: I added the event default (see above) and the page doesn't reload when I hit the submit button but goes to my view. The view sees that it isn't a POST since it is now  a GET and then I see on my console: 'status':'not post'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that best solution for this problem will be to dynamically assign post url in JavaScript.

Rewrite your template, so you can store somewhere your URL reversed by django, for example in `action` of form:

```
<form method = "POST" action="{% url "save_applicant" %}" class="form bgform" id="applicant_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ applicant_form|crispy }}
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="Save" />
</form>
```

And post AJAX to that URL instead of static one, it will be already with language prefix, so redirect won't happen:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#applicant_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault() //this will stop the file from submitting the form manually.
    $.ajax({
        url :$(this).attr('action'), // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { the_post : "Yay" }, // data sent with the post request
        dataType: "json",
        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Also: hardcoding URLS in template or Javascript is not good solution

Comment: thank you very much!! :) and thank you for showing me how to get the url without having to hardcode it.

Answer (score 1):

So I stepped away from the problem and realized my silly mistake. I just changed my urls.py to the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^save_applicant/','plan_b_profile.views.save_applicant',name='save_applicant'),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', 'plan_b_profile.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even using your own solution, you may still find that you receive a 302 redirect if you return a 404 Not Found status from your view when you use the i18n language extensions. I'm doing this when some of the request parameters are not correct (I'm using the same view for HTTP GETs and HTTP/AJAX POSTs).

The reason is that some Django middleware (I think LocaleMiddleware) will process the response on the way up the middleware stack, see that the page has not been found, and return a 302 redirect with the browser's language prefix prepended instead. Then, when this in turn is (in this case) not found by the next request, you'll get a different 404 Not Found response. This is bad because you never get to see the reason the original request failed.

In your case you could fix this by doing:

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^en/save_applicant/','plan_b_profile.views.save_applicant',name='save_applicant'),
]
...
```

This fools the offending middleware into thinking it is already a language-specific page (which actually it is since you return English in your button and ajax).

You could also remove redirects altogether using a solution like [solid-i18n-url](https://github.com/st4lk/django-solid-i18n-urls).

Edit: However on reflection it's probably a bad idea to return a 404 like this in the first place; a 400 Bad Request would be better..

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I was having the same issue with an HTTP 302 response from Django. Django will return an HTTP 302 if there is no trailing slash in the URL I do see one in your template code, but the Django log tells a different story):

```
[21/Aug/2015 20:53:43]"POST **/save_applicant** HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

Ensuring a trailing slash at the end of the URL (i.e. /save_applicant**/**) should make it work.

@GwynBleidD's answer, using the {% url %} template built-in is recommended.